# saving gray images in JPEG using Matlab imwrite

Tags: matlab, image-processing, jpeg

I am new to the world of image processing and would like to seek help with an issue I could not figure out. The issue is as follows:

I have a gray (black and white) image 'grayimage' which I want to save using the `imwrite` function in Matlab using JPEG format. I am using the following syntax:

```
imwrite(grayimage,cmap, 'imagename.jpg', 'jpeg');
```

Now, when I open the image file imagename.jpg using image viewers I don't see a gray image.   It's colored and a different image than desired.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong and options /parameters I am missing in `imwrite`?

I thought of converting the image to RGB and then save it in jpeg format. Will that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does your cmap comes from? Probably it is a "coloured" colormap. Try using a gray colormap:

```
cmap = colormap('gray');
imwrite(grayimage,cmap, 'imagename.jpg', 'jpeg');
```

More infos on colormap's: http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html

Comment: Thanks a lot and it works like a charm. I think I was using the default colourmap that was creating the problem. With the addition of the line cmap = colormap('gray') the gray colormap is correctly set.

Comment: Now gimme some thumbs up plz :-)

Comment: Please [accept this answer if it helped you solve your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). That will provide a clear indication that this question has been answered satisfactorily, provides future visitors an indicator about which answer worked (if any), and gives a little extra reputation to the one with the answer as an incentive to continue answering questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

it seems to me you have an indexed image with an associated colormap. You could use the [IND2GRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/ind2gray.html) function to convert it to a grayscale image before saving it to disk using [IMWRITE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imwrite.html):

```
I = ind2gray(grayimage,cmap);
imwrite(I,'imagename.jpg');
```

Comment: Amro, my image is not in index format, but is store in a jpeg file. I am reading that gray image from the jpeg file, doing box filtering on that gray image, and would like to store the resulting output gray image after filtering in the jpeg format. I can correctly see the output image i the imshow but when I save the same using imwrite in jpeg format, i see a kind of colored image in image viewer. Any pointers?

Comment: @Shan: your question is a bit confusing and lacks information; You say your image is not an indexed image, but yet you are using some kind of colormap... You should first understand the different kinds of [image types](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f14-13543.html) supported (binary,indexed,grayscale,truecolor).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression).

If you simply want a grayscale jpeg, probably easiest would be to install the `jpegtrans` program and use its `-grayscale` option to fiddle with the [chrominance channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrominance) of the image:

[image: colorful jpeg]
[image: converted to grayscale using jpegtrans]

A better option would be to output using a [lossless compression format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) such as [png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics).

(Thanks to the Wikipedia page on lossy compression for a perfect-sized color image to fiddle with.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am bit confused here as I want to use the imwrite function in a Matlab script to save the gray image in jpeg format. Is there any equivalent of jpegtrans in Matlab?